# Getting 403 (Forbidden) when trying to send POST to set_language view in Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'm new to Django and am trying to create a small website where I click on a flag and the language changes. I'm using django i18n for that:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
)
```

The problem is, when I run the following code:

**templetatags.py**

```
@register.simple_tag
def test():
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/i18n/setlang/', data = {'lang':'en', 'next' : '/'})
    print r.status_code
```

**home.html**

```
<div id='country_flags'>
    <a hreflang="en" href="{% test %}"><img id='en' src='{% static "mysyte/images/gb.png" %}'></a>
</div>
```

the result of r.status_code is 403.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the view `views.home` require a CSRF token when accepting post data?

Comment: Oh my god, that is my problem, I completely forgot about the CSRF token. Is there a way I can pass the token along with my request?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why would a *template tag* cause a post, and to your own app?

Comment: I think you can include a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` item in your input data dictionary.  However you can't give it just any value; it has to be the same value that the CSRF middleware layer is expecting, and I don't know how to get that value easily.

Comment: I'm using a POST because when using the Django translation, according to their documentation, the only way to manually set a language is sending  a POST request to the URL i18n/setlang. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#django.views.i18n.set_language

Answer (score 2):

Any POST request in django requires you to send the CSRF-Cookie by default. Your options around this:

- Don't use a POST request. Use GET instead.
- Send the CSRF-Token with the request. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/
- use the decorator `@csrf_exempt` to remove any csrf-protection from a view (in your case the view for `http://localhost:8000/i18n/setlang/`)
- don't send a request to your own app. use a link for the user to click on. probably your best option.

> Note:
>   if you want to use the decorator w/ a class-based view, decorate the dispatch() function of that view

Comment: Thank you for the options, ht_! The only reason I'm using a POST request is because, according to the Django documentation, the view responsible for changing the language of a website (set_language redirect view) only accepts POST requests to the i18n/setlang URL. But I'll try the other options.